# The first Weyl algebra is Calabi-Yau

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, duality-theorems, noncommutative-geometry

Why is the Weyl algebra $A_1(k)$ over a field $k$ Calabi-Yau?

*(My definition of Calabi-Yau is Ginzburg's)*

Comment: This was actually asked somewhere - I don't remember where...

Comment: well.. we have existence... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Koszul resolution $K_\bullet$ of $A=A_1(k)$ as an $A$-bimodule —this was probably first constructed in  [Sridharan, R. Filtered algebras and representations of Lie algebras. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 100 1961 530--550. MR0130900 (24 #A754)] (which you can find [here](http://www.ams.org/tran/1961-100-03/S0002-9947-1961-0130900-1/S0002-9947-1961-0130900-1.pdf)); you can find a description of the complex [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0109068).

Since $K_\bullet$ is of finite length and its homogeneous components are finitely generated free $A$-bimodules, we see that $A$ satisfies the required finiteness conditions.

To compute $Ext_{A^e}^\bullet(A,A\otimes A)$ we have to find the homology of the complex $\hom_{A^e}(K,A\otimes A)$. If you look at it for a while, you will see that there is in fact an isomorphism of complexes of $A$-bimodules $$\hom_{A^e}(K,A\otimes A) \cong K_\bullet$$ so we immediately see that $A$ is Calabi-Yau.

Comment: You accepted this yet you certainly did not try to do any of the steps I sketched, simply because you did not have time.

Comment: Nono I trust the answer but am currently sketching the steps and reading the article (I should have it all worked out by tomorrow afternoon)

Comment: Hey Mariano, (so I had put this result on the backburner for a couple weeks and just now and re-looking over afew steps) However.. I'm curious about one thing (which you seem to use) at the bottom of page: 27 of *http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612139v3.pdf Ginzburg* claims that for an algebra (not DG), his (and my) definition of $d$-calabi-Yau is equivalent to Ext_i(A,A^e}, vanishing in all degrees except for possibly $d$.  Why is this true?

Comment: Suppose $A$ is an algebra. If there is an iso $Rhom_{A^e}(A,A\otimes A)\cong A[-d]$, taking homology shows that $Ext_{A^e}^p(A,A\otimes A)$ is $0$ if $p\neq d$ and $A$ if $p=d$. Conversely, if we have this description of the Ext (and $A$ is homologically smooth, of course), then $A$ admits van den Bergh duality, and $Rhom_{A^e}(A,A\otimes A)\cong A\otimes_{A^e}^L(A\otimes A)[-d]=A[-d]$.

Comment: Perfect!  I finally finished all the details, thank you so much Mariano for your direction with the Weyl algebras!  Your a really cool guy! :D